# Is possible to use pyodbc executemany to update multiple rows in a SQL Table?

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc, execute, executemany

I have used `pyodbc.executemany` to insert items in database tables. I am trying to update multiple rows using `pyodbc.executemany` and I keep getting errors. Is it possible to use `pyodbc.executemany` for updating multiple rows?

Here is my code:

```
import pyodbc
import os
listTest=[('okAa','a'),('OKBb','b')]

queryToTest="UPDATE AllTrasactions2 SET [Barcode]=? WHERE [Location]=?"
strForDB = os.getcwd() + '\DBINFO.txt'
openDBFile = open(strForDB, 'r')
currentDirForDB = openDBFile.read()
dbPath = currentDirForDB

con = pyodbc.connect(dbPath)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.executemany(queryToTest,listTest)
con.commit()
```

This is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Test/test.py", line 13, in <module>
    cur.executemany(queryToTest,listTest)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'AllTrasactions2'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")
```

Comment: By chance is your table actually named "AllTransactions2" (with an"n")?

Comment: Yes. Is that bad practice?

Comment: No, it just means that there's a typo in your query.

Comment: Probably the dumbest thing I have done today. Thank you very much.